# How to restart an aribtrary application from a Mac OS app

Tags: swift, macos

I inherited a Mac OS project and I need to restart the browser (and potentially other applications/services).

This is my first time working with Desktop applications, previous experience is mostly mobile.

Are there any process management Swift APIs I can use? Or I should just go with `system()` or `execv()` and the likes?

Killing and starting other processes will require elevated privileges I presume. Are there APIs in Swift I can use to take care of password prompts or that's something I need to take care of myself?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the running applications using NSWorkspace. There is no way AFAIK to "restart" an application but you can terminate or forceTerminate and then open it again.

To get the running applications:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
```

To terminate an application:

```
runningApp.terminate()
```

To force teminate an application:

```
runningApp.forceTerminate()
```

To open an application that was running you just need to get the bundle identifier from the application that was running and then open it again

```
if let bundleIdentifier = runningApplications[index].bundleIdentifier {
    runningApplications[index].forceTerminate()
    NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(withBundleIdentifier: bundleIdentifier, options: .default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifier: nil)
}
```